# Using array values to init new array elements

Tags: arrays, swift, exc-bad-instruction

I've put together the following sample code:

```
let tings = [1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 8]

class Foo {
    var number: Int
    init(something: Int) {
        self.number = something
    }
}

var list: [Foo] = []
for num in tings {
    var temp = Foo(something: tings[num])         //excbadinstruction invop
    list.append(Foo(something: 3))                //no error
    list.append(Foo(something: Int(4)))           //no error
    list.append(Foo(something: tings[num]))       //excbadinstruction invop
    list.append(Foo(something: Int(tings[num])))  //excbadinstruction invop
}
```

I dont get what the problem is with the last two lines as in my opinion things[num] also is of type Int, and same of course with the last row.

If I specify the type of things to be [Int], nothing changes (which isnt strange to me)
I also have to explicitly state 'something:' which I didn't expect because it was the first and only argument of the initializer.

I hope anyone can explain this to me and/or give the right way to do this.

Comment: "Int" is an "struct" in Swift language and you cannot subscript using struct.

Comment: `tings` is an `[Int]`... not an `Int`.  He's subscripting an array.

Comment: @nhgrif no, tings is an [Int], however tings[num] is an Int

Comment: Right.  I didn't say anything else.  gagarwal's comment is incorrect and I'm posting an answer.

Comment: @nhgrif I dunno what you mean, but do you know how to do this the righ way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swift Playground is fun and all, but it's pretty terrible when it comes to debugging.

If we duplicate this code in an actual compilable and build able application, we get no build time warnings or errors.  However, as soon as we hit play and run the code, the problem is obvious.  The console prints:

```
fatal error: Array index out of bounds
```

Here's the problem... our array has six elements.  That means the maximum accessible index is 5.

Look at our loop:

```
for num in tings {
    // do stuff
}
```

If we change the loop to print `num`, like this:

```
for num in tings {
    println(num)
}
```

You'll see that it prints our `tings` array:

```
1
2
4
5
6
8
```

Now let's access the the element at each index:

```
for num in tings {
    println(tings[num])
}
```

What prints?

```
2
4
6
8
fatal error: Array index out of range
```

What happened?

We tried to access the 6th index, because the fifth iteration of the loop, the fifth element of the array, is the `Int` 6.  We're trying to access the 6th element, which is out of bounds for our array.

---

If you're trying to iterate of the elements of `tings` and instantiate a `Foo` for each element, you simply need this:

```
for num in tings {
    list.append(Foo(something: num))
}
```

Or as Paul points out in a comment, if you need the index, you can iterate through the loop as such:

```
for (index, value) in enumerate(tings) {
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: And if you want the indexes: for (index, value) in enumerate(tings) {

Comment: Thank you, with your explanation in mind I've read the section in Apples swift guide about for-in-loops again and now its clear to me. Thank you very much!